# Access an element in an object with Selenium IDE

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, selenium-ide

Selenium IDE

I have a problem with retrieving ID of html page which is included in another html page

the page1.html contains:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>page1</title>
</head>
<body>
...... code
<object type="text/html" data="page2.html" width="848" height="720"></object>
...... code
</body>
</html>
```

The page2.html contains:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>page2</title>
</head>
<body>
...... code
<span><input type="text" id="myID" size="6" value="val"></span>
...... code
</body>
</html>
```

Selenium code:
i tried:

```
window.document.getElementById("myID").value = 'myValue';}
```

and:

```
window.onload=function(){document.getElementById("myID").value = 'myValue';}
```

no one works i have this Error:

```
[error] Threw an exception: window.document.getElementById(...) is null
```

My objectif is:
I want that Selenium modify value of the input.

value="myValue" instead of value="val"

when i test that in the page2.html with Selenium it works well but when i test that in page1.html it does not work i have error null ....
this is an exemple of my code Selenium:

```
<tr>
<td>open</td>
<td>file:///D:/Documents/page1.html</td>
<td></td>
</tr>

<tr> 
<td>storeEval</td> 
<td>window.document.object.getElementById('myID').value = 'myValue';</td> 
<td>var1</td> 
</tr>
```

can some one help me !

Thanks

Comment: When you say "... html page which is included in another html page ...", are we talking about frames?

Comment: No like you see in my code i have html page "page1.html" in this page i have <object type="text/html" data="page2.html" width="848" height="720"></object>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
window.document.getElementById("myID")
```

Instead of

```
window.document.getElementById("MyID")
```

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById)

> id is a case-sensitive string representing the unique ID of the
>   element being sought.

Comment: yes i have made a mistake. but even i correct it i have same problem